# Is it possible to build a custom loss function of chamfer distance using Keras

Tags: keras

In my assignment about the point cloud,I need to use a keras custom loss function of chamfer distance and apply it to the autoencoder.But I find it is hard to implement the function.

I have tried to write in this way.I hope someone could help me.

```
def chamfer_loss_func(y_true,y_pred):
    '''
    Calculate the chamfer distance,use euclidean metric
    :param y_true:
    :param y_pred:
    :return:
    '''
    batch_size = 32
    y_true = K.reshape(y_true,[batch_size,2048,3])
    y_pred = K.reshape(y_pred, [batch_size, 2048, 3])
    num_t = K.int_shape(y_true)[1]
    num_p = K.int_shape(y_pred)[1]
    dists_mat = K.zeros(shape=[num_t, num_p])
    sum = 0.0
    for bi in range(batch_size):
        for i in range(num_t):
            pnt_t = y_true[bi][i]
            for j in range(num_p):
                if (i <= j):
                    pnt_p = y_pred[bi][j]
                    dists_mat[i][j] = K.eval(K.sum(K.sqrt(tf.subtract(pnt_t, pnt_p))))
                else:
                    dists_mat[i][j] = dists_mat[j][i]
        dist_t_to_p = K.mean(K.min(dists_mat, axis=0))
        dist_p_to_t = K.mean(K.min(dists_mat, axis=1))
        sum += K.max([dist_p_to_t, dist_t_to_p])
    return sum / batch_size
```

And the network structure is listed here:

```
def get_model(num_pnts):
    input_tensor = Input(shape=[num_pnts, 3])
    input_cov_tensor = Input(shape=[num_pnts, 9]) # add the local covariance matrix
    # the encoder network
    concat_1 = concatenate([input_tensor, input_cov_tensor])  # concatenate the two input tensor
    dense_1 = Dense(32,activation='relu')(concat_1)
    dense_2 = Dense(64,activation='relu')(dense_1)
    dense_3 = Dense(128,activation='relu')(dense_2)
    encoded = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=num_pnts)(dense_3)
    # the decoder network
    # use 3 fully connected layers
    dense_3 = Dense(128,activation='relu')(encoded)
    dense_4 = Dense(128,activation='relu')(dense_3)
    dense_5 = Dense(num_pnts*3,activation='linear')(dense_4)
    decoded = Reshape(target_shape=[num_pnts,3])(dense_5)
    #the autoencoder
    autoencoder = Model(inputs=[input_tensor,input_cov_tensor],outputs=decoded)
    return autoencoder
```

And the place where uses the loss function:

```
model = get_model(2048)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=chamfer_loss_func,)
```

Comment: Did you get any error messages?

Comment: Yes.Here it is.tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'reshape_1_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?,?]
  [[Node: reshape_1_target = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,?,?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

Comment: And what's more, it is very strange that the method K.update_sub can not replace the method tf.subtract.

Comment: Can you also paste the piece of code which you call and run this function?

Comment: Sure, already added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you give me the link of chamfer distance you reference to?
`K.sum(K.sqrt(tf.subtract(pnt_t, pnt_p)))` looks strange to me. To calculate Euclidean distance, the `sqrt` should be replaced with `square`.

And it is not recommended to use for loop in tensorflow, so I have reimplemented it:

```
import numpy as np
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, MaxPooling1D, Reshape, concatenate
from keras.models import Model

def dists_mat_calculater(pnts_t, pnts_p):
    """
    arguments:
        pnts_t : from y_true[bi], shape: (num_t, 3)
        pnts_p : from y_pred[bi], shape: (num_p, 3)

    return:
        dists_mat: shape: (num_t, num_p)
    """
    num_t = K.int_shape(pnts_t)[0]
    num_p = K.int_shape(pnts_p)[0]

    pnts_t = tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(pnts_t, 1), [1, 1, num_p]), [-1, 3])
    pnts_p = tf.tile(pnts_p, [num_t, 1])

    dists_mat = K.sum(K.square(tf.subtract(pnts_t, pnts_p)), axis=1)
    dists_mat = tf.reshape(dists_mat, [num_t, num_p])
    dists_mat_upper = tf.matrix_band_part(dists_mat, 0, -1)
    dists_mat_symm = dists_mat_upper + tf.transpose(dists_mat_upper)
    dists_mat_symm = tf.matrix_set_diag(dists_mat_symm, tf.diag_part(dists_mat))  

    return dists_mat_symm

def dist_calculator(pnts):
    """
    arguments:
        pnts_t : from y_true[bi], shape: (num_t, 3)
        pnts_p : from y_pred[bi], shape: (num_p, 3)

    return:
        dist: shape: (1, )
    """
    pnts_t, pnts_p = pnts
    dists_mat = dists_mat_calculater(pnts_t, pnts_p)
    dist_t_to_p = K.mean(K.min(dists_mat, axis=0)) #shape: (1,)
    dist_p_to_t = K.mean(K.min(dists_mat, axis=1)) #shape: (1,)
    dist = K.max([dist_p_to_t, dist_t_to_p]) #shape: (1,)
    return dist

def chamfer_loss_func_tf(y_true,y_pred):
    '''
    Calculate the chamfer distance,use euclidean metric
    :param y_true:
    :param y_pred:
    :return:
    '''
    y_true = K.reshape(y_true,[-1, num_pnts, 3])
    y_pred = K.reshape(y_pred, [-1, num_pnts, 3])
    return K.mean(tf.map_fn(dist_calculator, elems=(y_true, y_pred), dtype=tf.float32))
```

`dists_mat_calculater` calculate the distance matrix, and the part of pairwise calculation is enlightened by [Mask R-CNN - overlaps_graph](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/mrcnn/model.py#L457).

I also implement a pure python version for validation purpose:

```
def chamfer_loss_python(y_true,y_pred):
    '''
    Calculate the chamfer distance,use euclidean metric
    :param y_true:
    :param y_pred:
    :return:
    '''
    y_true = np.reshape(y_true,[-1,num_pnts,3])
    y_pred = np.reshape(y_pred, [-1,num_pnts, 3])
    batch_size = y_true.shape[0]
    num_t = y_true.shape[1]
    num_p = y_pred.shape[1]
    dists_mat = np.zeros((num_t, num_p))
    _sum = 0.0
    loss_before_mean_py = []
    for bi in range(batch_size):
        for i in range(num_t):
            pnt_t = y_true[bi][i]
            for j in range(num_p):
                pnt_p = y_pred[bi][j]
                if (i <= j):
                    pnt_p = y_pred[bi][j]
                    dists_mat[i][j] = np.sum((pnt_t - pnt_p)**2)
                else:
                    dists_mat[i][j] = dists_mat[j][i]

        dist_t_to_p = np.mean(np.min(dists_mat, axis=0))
        dist_p_to_t = np.mean(np.min(dists_mat, axis=1))
        _sum += np.max([dist_p_to_t, dist_t_to_p])
        loss_before_mean_py.append(np.max([dist_p_to_t, dist_t_to_p]))
    return _sum / batch_size
```

Following is the testing script:

```
num_pnts = 8
np.random.seed(1)
Y_true = np.random.randn(32, num_pnts, 3).astype(np.float32)
Y_pred = np.random.randn(32, num_pnts, 3).astype(np.float32)

Y_true_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, num_pnts, 3), name="Y_true_ph")
Y_pred_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, num_pnts, 3), name="Y_pred_ph")

loss = chamfer_loss_func_tf(Y_true_ph, Y_pred_ph)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    loss = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={
            Y_true_ph: Y_true,
            Y_pred_ph: Y_pred})

loss_py = chamfer_loss_python(Y_true,Y_pred)
print(loss)
print(loss_py)
```

Comment: Oh, the same mistake as before.  You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'reshape_1_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?,?]
  [[Node: reshape_1_target = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,?,?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

Comment: Hi bro, suppose there are two point sets S and S' with the same point numbers, e.g. 2048.Then their chamfer distance = sum(min_euclidean_distance(s,s')). where s is the point in the set S and s' is the point in the set S'. min_euclidean_distance means the smallest smallest distance. This is why, I need to build a distance matrix in my method. Thanks for your kind attention.

Comment: If this solution works for you, please kindly accept it. :)